# Detect rotation of camera output C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, motion-detection

I have a problem that I have not been able to find a thread about.

I have a camera feed of a circular object which I need to rotate BUT I want to **detect the rotation of the object**. If the object is rotated clockwise or counterclockwise. In the end I want to, for example, draw an rectangle on the object and that rectangle will the rotate the same direction as the object in the camera feed.

The camera feed (shown in GIF below) it's processed with Otsus algorithm and the object is always deformed somehow (i.e. it's not 100% round).

I looked into various motion detection algorithms and by comparing two frames you can get the motion if the object moves across the frame. But the methods won't work to determine the rotation.

If someone could be so kind to help me or to direct me to the correct direction I would be very grateful. And as before, if I'm being unclear I will of course try to explain further. Thank you!

[image: Rotation of object]

Comment: Do you have influence on the input data? For example, could you ask for a "Marker" in the image besides the "main" Object? Another thing would be Meta-Data. Some motorized Cameras will attach Meta-Data to the images about their current position. That of course would not be usable if you need to be "Camera-Model-Agnostic".

Comment: Oh wait, does that "circular object" happen to be a colon or some inside of a pipe or pipe-like structure? In that case a marker is out of sight, unfortunately.

Comment: No, the object is not inside a pipe or pipe-like structure. But I'm not rotating the camera, I'm rotating the object :) I'm guessing I need to establish a fixed point (like the dents) and then compare them between the frames. But I don't know how reliable it would be.

Comment: Well, if you have control over the rotation, I'd try and include that info in the meta-data, somehow.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I only rotate the object by hand so it would be difficult to take account of that rotation in the program :)

Comment: And an optical marker is out of the game? Maybe something like a "crosshair" with "north" marker or 4 corner-dots like in a QR code ...

Comment: ^^ Why I am advertising for this? Using a marker in the object itself is really hard to do. For one: What seems to be working fine in this example may fail miserably in the next (different) object. Using a "dent" means: You can a) identify the dent (the dent is THE dent), b) you can _precisely_ (enough) compute the position of the dent (and its rotation). And c) the same algorithms work on any of these objects with dents with a high enough confidence. - Just to give a hint of what you need to tackle...

Comment: BTW: How precise do you need to be? To the ° ? To a fraction of a ° ?

Comment: Oh and I would not "compare images". I'd probaly detect the center of the object and get a measure of the radius in each n° (probably 360 for starters). Then you should be able to detect patterns in those measurements and tell the rotation against a "0°" reference. This is assuming the objects in question are similar and "roundish".

Comment: From the video in the question, I suspect you are having reflections, too. You may want to optimize your lighting to have no outside noise (shadows, additional light) and as few mirror effects / reflections as possible.